# derivation of the cubic formula

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, cubics

In my research I came across the following derivation of the cubic formula that was almost complete. However at the end it says to make  the substitution $u=z^3$ which would determine the roots. I am not quite sure how to do this and then how to determine the roots and I am looking for some help.

A general form for the cubic equation is,

$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0 \tag{1}$$

To find the roots of this equation we first try to get rid of the quadratic term $x^2$. The substitution $x=y-\dfrac{b}{3a}$ helps in achieving our goal. This results in, $$ay^3+\left(c-\dfrac{b^2}{3a}\right)y+\left(d+\dfrac{2b^3}{27a^2}-\dfrac{bc}{3a}\right)=0\tag{2}$$ which we transform into the following, $$y^3+\dfrac{1}{a}\left(c-\dfrac{b^2}{3a}\right)y+\dfrac{1}{a}\left(d+\dfrac{2b^3}{27a^2}-\dfrac{bc}{3a}\right)=0\tag{3}$$ Upon assuming $e=\dfrac{1}{a}\left(c-\dfrac{b^2}{3a}\right)$ and $f=\dfrac{1}{a}\left(d+\dfrac{2b^3}{27a^2}-\dfrac{bc}{3a}\right)$ we get the equation as, $$y^3+ey+f=0\tag{4}$$ We reduce this equation by the substitution $y=z+\dfrac{s}{z}$ and choosing $s=-\dfrac{e}{3}$ we obtain the simplified equation as, $$z^6+fz^3-\dfrac{e^3}{27}=0\tag{5}$$ What only remains is to make the substitution $u=z^3$.

Comment: You would just have $$u^2+fu-e^3/27=0$$, which you can solve using the quadratic formula.

Comment: so then there is only 2 roots?

Comment: No. You would only have one from the quadratic formula, and because you do $u=z^3$, you need to take a cube root, and cube roots have three roots, analogous to how square roots have two roots. For example, $z^3=1$ has 3 roots: see http://www.math-only-math.com/the-cube-roots-of-unity.html

Comment: In fact, I asked a very similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358214/cubic-formula-derivation-check-and-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We start with the substitution  $z^3=u$ and obtain a quadratic  equation in $u$
>   \begin{align*}
> z^6+fz^3-\frac{e^3}{27}&=0\\
> u^2+fu-\frac{e^3}{27}&=0\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> We solve the quadratic equation (1) and get
>   \begin{align*}
> u_{0,1}=-\frac{f}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{f^2}{4}+\frac{e^3}{27}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $z^3=u$ we obtain from (2)
>
> \begin{align*}
> z_{0,1}=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{f}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{f^2}{4}+\frac{e^3}{27}}}
> \end{align*}

We are free to select either $z_0$ or $z_1$ and we choose $z_0$. Since $z^3=u$ we know  there are three solutions
\begin{align*}
z_0,z_0 e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}},z_0 e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}} \tag{3}
\end{align*}

> From (3) we can calculate the three solutions for $x$ via
>   \begin{align*}
> y=z-\frac{s}{3z}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x=y-\frac{b}{3a}
> \end{align*}
>
> We finally obtain with $\omega_1=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$
>   \begin{align*}
> x_0&=z_0-\frac{s}{3z_0}-\frac{b}{3a}\\
> x_1&=z_0\omega_1-\frac{s}{3z\omega_1}-\frac{b}{3a}\\
> x_2&=z_0\omega_1^2-\frac{s}{3z\omega_1^2}-\frac{b}{3a}
> \end{align*}

**[2017-11-05] Add-on:** Let's make an example to see the formulas in action.

Find the solutions of
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{x^3-7x^2+14x-8=0}
\end{align*}

> - **Step 1:** We consider $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ and calculate $x=y-\frac{b}{3a}$.
>
>   We set $x=y+\frac{7}{3}$ and obtain
>     \begin{align*}
>   y^3-\frac{7}{3}y-\frac{20}{27}=0
>   \end{align*}
> - **Step 2:** We consider $y^3+ey+f=0$ and calculate $y=z-\frac{e}{3z}$.
>
>   We set $y=z+\frac{7}{9z}$ which gives
>     \begin{align*}
>   729z^6-540 z^3+343=0
>   \end{align*}
> - **Step 3:** We substitute $z^3=u$ and solve the quadratic equation
>
>   \begin{align*}
>   729u^2-540 u+343=0
>   \end{align*}
>
>   We obtain
>
>   \begin{align*}
>   u_{1,2}=\frac{10}{27}\pm\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}
>   \end{align*}
> - **Step 4:** The cubic roots $z_0,z_0\omega_1,z_0\omega_2$
>
>   We select $u_1=\frac{10}{27}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$ and calculate the three cubic roots:
>
>   \begin{align*}
>   z_0&=\sqrt[3]{\frac{10}{27}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}}=\frac{1}{6}\left(5+i\sqrt{3}\right)\\
>   z_0\omega_1&=z_0e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}=\frac{1}{3}\left(-2+i\sqrt{3}\right)\\
>   z_0\omega_2&=z_0e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}=-\frac{1}{6}\left(1+3i\sqrt{3}\right)\\
>   \end{align*}
> - **Step 5:** The solutions $x_0,x_1,x_2$
>
>   Finally we can calculate the solutions from $z_0,z_1,z_2$ via
>     \begin{align*}
>   x=y-\frac{b}{3a}=z-\frac{e}{3z}-\frac{b}{3a}
>   \end{align*}
>
>   We obtain
>     \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{x_0}&=z_0+\frac{7}{9z_0}+\frac{7}{3}\color{blue}{=4}\\
>   \color{blue}{x_1}&=z_0\omega_1+\frac{7}{9z_0\omega_1}+\frac{7}{3}\color{blue}{=1}\\
>   \color{blue}{x_2}&=z_0\omega_2+\frac{7}{9z_0\omega_2}+\frac{7}{3}\color{blue}{=2}\\
>   \end{align*}
>     and conclude
>     \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{x^3-7x^2+14x-8=(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)=0}
>   \end{align*}

*Note:* Working with the conjugate complex $u_2=\overline{u_1}=\frac{10}{27}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$ instead of $u_1$ gives the complex conjugates $\overline{z_1},\overline{z_1}e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and $\overline{z_1}e^{-\frac{4\pi i}{3}}$ and leads (of course) to the same results $x_0=4,x_1=1$ and $x_2=2$.

Comment: the part where it says from 3 the solutions to x via y and x, do you mean subsiting those two equations in?

Comment: @mt12345: Correct. I did the same in the example too.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer When you are solving example, you come to a "Step 4" where you select $u_1$ over $u_2$ and completely forget about $u_2$. Why is this possible? I mean why is it possible to ignore one half of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The cubic formula was derived from a series of substitutions. It's probably better to memorize the process of deriving the formula, rather than memorizing the actual formula.

Starting with the general cubic, make a substitution such that the squared term is removed. Let's denote the depressed cubic as$$x^3+qx+r=0$$Now, set $x=y+z$. Expanding and factoring gives$$y^3+z^3+(3yz+q)(y+z)+r=0$$Setting $3yz+q=0$ gives $$y=-\frac q{3z}$$If we substitute that in, we get a quadratic in $y^3$. Using the quadratic formula, we get the roots of $y^3$ and $z^3$ respectively. Therefore, we have the solution as$$x_1=\color{blue}{\left\{-\frac r2+\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\tfrac 13}+\left\{-\frac r2-\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4-\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\tfrac 13}}$$

---

The other solutions can be found using the cube roots of unity.$$\omega=-\frac 12+\frac {i\sqrt{3}}2\qquad\omega^2=-\frac 12-\frac {i\sqrt3}2$$So$$\begin{align*} & x_2=\color{blue}{\omega\left\{-\frac r2+\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}+\omega^2\left\{-\frac r2-\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}}\\ & x_3=\color{blue}{\omega^2\left\{-\frac r2+\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}+\omega\left\{-\frac r2-\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}}\end{align*}$$